# npm install -g phonegap

Tags: node.js, cordova

After Installing NodeJs and running npm install -g phonegap I get a result that is in a completely different format than it should be:

C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install -g phonegap
|

> ws@0.4.31 install C:\Users\Aashubhai\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
>   \phonegap\node_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engi
>   ne.io\node_modules\ws
>
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

Please suggest if there any other workaround. Tired of this error from past 3 days. no luck in installing phonegap.

Comment: what's wrong with that message and the format you got?

Comment: updated the error msg

Answer (score 0):

Path variable had to be updated with C:\Windows\System32 and it installed phonegap.

Answer (score -1):

1. `npm install -g cordova`
2. `npm install -g phonegap`